# Can't alight TextView toRightOf ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

The TextView doesn't alight to right (end) of ImageView for some reason. See battery image and its percents.

**Current:**

[image]

**Expected:**

[image]

**The code:**

```
...
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.3">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:id="@+id/battery_level"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/battery_level"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/battery_level"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/battery_level"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/battery_level"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:id="@+id/battery_level_percents"
        style="@style/Blue_TextViewStyle"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
...
```

**Any idea what causes that behaviour?**

---

**EDIT:**
If I hardcode image source to `ImageView` and text to `TextView` then it looks like in Design view:

[image]

the code of it:

```
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
```

Seems like even `wrap_content` doesn't work.

Comment: Change `RelativeLayout` width into `wrap_content` and Remove the `layout_weight`

Comment: And you can check your `Blue_TextViewStyle`. Maybe there are some attributes, that causes your behaviour.

Comment: Looks like RelativeLayout is inside LinearLayout.. wat s the orientation of LinearLayout??

Comment: @rom4ek, in `Blue_TextViewStyle` there're only `textSize`, `textColor`, `textStyle` and `fontFamily` parameters

Comment: @anushabh, orientation of root `LinearLayout` is vertical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to your ImageView.

The Bounds might be to big if the source picture was larger.

Comment: Thanks alot! That was it! For some reasons bounds of image were wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/battery_level"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/battery_level"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/battery_level"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/battery_level"
    android:text="New Text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You've just removed layout_weight param and the rest is basically the same. I need that weight. No changes except the structure of UI elements got broken

Comment: you can't use layout_weight in relative layout!!! and i have change the width & height of your layout to wrap_content, android:layout_toRightOf to your text & your are using Fill_parent...

Comment: Why can't I use it? It works fine with no errors. Its needed to set up weight inside root layout.

Comment: ok...declare it but it is useless .... in relative layout click on W and use cltr+spacebar for searching the param of relative layout you will see it only shows width option not the weight.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Like This.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/battery_level"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/battery_level_percents"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That didn't work. And I need that `layout_weight` since the entire UI structure is based on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```